# Как настроить переключение задач из Kanboard, триггером в Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция, jenkins-pipeline, json-rpc, ci-cd

Собираю 3 сервиса через docker-compose: Jenkins, Kanboard(таск-менеджер), Gitea. Задача: по пушу в локальный репозиторий Gitea собирать проект в Jenkins и если все успешно, изменять задачу в Kanboard. Нашел плагин для Jenkins, который позволяет это сделать - https://github.com/jenkinsci/kanboard-plugin. Документации никакой, написано только что нужно настроить заголовок "X-API-Auth" в Kanboard по инструкции(https://docs.kanboard.org/en/latest/api/authentication.html). С API/jsonrpc никогда не работал, поэтому возникли проблемы. Не понятно, что писать в config.php при сборке контейнера(просто `define('API_AUTHENTICATION_HEADER', 'X-API-Auth');` не работает) и что прописывать в Kanboard Publisher.
В консоли при подключении:

```
kanboard_1  | PHP message: Kanboard: user Unknown authentication failure with IP address: 172.19.0.1"
kanboard_1  | PHP message: [error] API authentication failure for "
kanboard_1  | 2021/06/22 16:23:26 [error] 16#16: *16 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: Kanboard: user Unknown authentication failure with IP address: 172.19.0.1PHP message: [error] API authentication failure for" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /jsonrpc.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.1.80"
```

[image: Настройки для плагина в Jenkins]

[image: данные из самого Kanboard]

Answer (score 0):

Решил исправлением конфига docker-compose.yml(добавил переменную окружения):

```
kanboard:
    build: 
      context: kanboard
    networks:
      - devops
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - API_AUTHENTICATION_HEADER=X-API-Auth
    volumes:
      - ./data/kanboard_data/app_data:/var/www/app/data
      - ./data/kanboard_data/kanboard_plugins:/var/www/app/plugins
      - ./data/kanboard_data/kanboard_ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
```